# Unable to convert the pytorch model to the TorchScript format

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, multiviews

Loaded the pretrained PyTorch model file, and when I try to run it with torch.jit.script I get the below error, When I try to run the inbuilt pretrained model from pytorch.org it works perfectly fine. (Ex. [Link to example code](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/model_preparation_android.html)) but throws error for custom built pretrained model ([Git repo containing the pretrained model weights](https://github.com/AaltoML/GP-MVS)), ([pretrained weight](https://github.com/HKUST-Aerial-Robotics/MVDepthNet))

```
encoder = enCoder()
encoder = torch.nn.DataParallel(encoder)
encoder.load_state_dict(weights['state_dict'])
encoder.eval()

torchscript_model = torch.jit.script(encoder)

# Error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotSupportedError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
[<ipython-input-30-1d9f30e14902>](https://localhost:8080/#) in <module>()
      1 # torch.quantization.convert(encoder, inplace=True)
      2 
----> 3 torchscript_model = torch.jit.script(encoder)

8 frames
[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/jit/_script.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in script(obj, optimize, _frames_up, _rcb, example_inputs)
   1256         obj = call_prepare_scriptable_func(obj)
   1257         return torch.jit._recursive.create_script_module(
-> 1258             obj, torch.jit._recursive.infer_methods_to_compile
   1259         )
   1260 

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in create_script_module(nn_module, stubs_fn, share_types, is_tracing)
    449     if not is_tracing:
    450         AttributeTypeIsSupportedChecker().check(nn_module)
--> 451     return create_script_module_impl(nn_module, concrete_type, stubs_fn)
    452 
    453 def create_script_module_impl(nn_module, concrete_type, stubs_fn):

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in create_script_module_impl(nn_module, concrete_type, stubs_fn)
    461     """
    462     cpp_module = torch._C._create_module_with_type(concrete_type.jit_type)
--> 463     method_stubs = stubs_fn(nn_module)
    464     property_stubs = get_property_stubs(nn_module)
    465     hook_stubs, pre_hook_stubs = get_hook_stubs(nn_module)

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in infer_methods_to_compile(nn_module)
    730     stubs = []
    731     for method in uniqued_methods:
--> 732         stubs.append(make_stub_from_method(nn_module, method))
    733     return overload_stubs + stubs
    734 

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in make_stub_from_method(nn_module, method_name)
     64     # In this case, the actual function object will have the name `_forward`,
     65     # even though we requested a stub for `forward`.
---> 66     return make_stub(func, method_name)
     67 
     68 

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/jit/_recursive.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in make_stub(func, name)
     49 def make_stub(func, name):
     50     rcb = _jit_internal.createResolutionCallbackFromClosure(func)
---> 51     ast = get_jit_def(func, name, self_name="RecursiveScriptModule")
     52     return ScriptMethodStub(rcb, ast, func)
     53 

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/jit/frontend.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in get_jit_def(fn, def_name, self_name, is_classmethod)
    262         pdt_arg_types = type_trace_db.get_args_types(qualname)
    263 
--> 264     return build_def(parsed_def.ctx, fn_def, type_line, def_name, self_name=self_name, pdt_arg_types=pdt_arg_types)
    265 
    266 # TODO: more robust handling of recognizing ignore context manager

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/jit/frontend.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in build_def(ctx, py_def, type_line, def_name, self_name, pdt_arg_types)
    300                        py_def.col_offset + len("def"))
    301 
--> 302     param_list = build_param_list(ctx, py_def.args, self_name, pdt_arg_types)
    303     return_type = None
    304     if getattr(py_def, 'returns', None) is not None:

[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/jit/frontend.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in build_param_list(ctx, py_args, self_name, pdt_arg_types)
    324         expr = py_args.kwarg
    325         ctx_range = ctx.make_range(expr.lineno, expr.col_offset - 1, expr.col_offset + len(expr.arg))
--> 326         raise NotSupportedError(ctx_range, _vararg_kwarg_err)
    327     if py_args.vararg is not None:
    328         expr = py_args.vararg

NotSupportedError: Compiled functions can't take variable number of arguments or use keyword-only arguments with defaults:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 147
    def forward(self, *inputs, **kwargs):
                                ~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
        with torch.autograd.profiler.record_function("DataParallel.forward"):
            if not self.device_ids:
`
    
### Versions

Collecting environment information...
PyTorch version: 1.10.0+cu111
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 11.1
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (x86_64)
GCC version: (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Clang version: 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
CMake version: version 3.12.0
Libc version: glibc-2.26

Python version: 3.7.13 (default, Mar 16 2022, 17:37:17)  [GCC 7.5.0] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Linux-5.4.144+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 11.1.105
GPU models and configuration: Could not collect
Nvidia driver version: Could not collect
cuDNN version: Probably one of the following:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.7.6.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.8.0.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8.0.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_adv_train.so.8.0.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8.0.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8.0.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8.0.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_ops_train.so.8.0.5
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.21.6
[pip3] torch==1.10.0+cu111
[pip3] torchaudio==0.10.0+cu111
[pip3] torchsummary==1.5.1
[pip3] torchtext==0.11.0
[pip3] torchvision==0.11.1+cu111
[conda] Could not collect
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`torch.jit.script` create a ScriptFunction(a Function with Graph) by parsing the python source code from module.forward().
If your module contains some grammar cannot support by the python parser, it will failed. Especially for the object not contains a static type.

Using `torch.jit.trace` is able to avoid such problems. It creates Graph in the op call process (c++ way). It will never failed, but cannot handle if-else branch cases. If you have branches, you should trace it every iteration which leading to 2 forward 1 backward in each training process. With no-brach model, you can reuse the traced ScriptFunction.